# Global worpress database query in php file is giving 500 error

Tags: php, database, wordpress, connection

Ok guys please help me here i am really stucked

I have declared an external database in functions.php like this

```
function connect_recipes_db() {
    global $recipesdb;
   $recipesdb = new wpdb( 'usr', 'pass', 'dbname', 'localhost');
}
add_action('init', 'connect_recipes_db');
```

i created a plugin and used

```
global $recipesdb;

$NDBNo = $_POST['NDBNo'];
$result = $recipesdb->get_results(
        "SELECT * FROM IngredientsTable WHERE NDB_No LIKE'$NDBNo%' ORDER BY NDB_No ASC");
```

and its working fine

now inside a javascript i have an ajax call to a php file posting some data and expecting some results from a db query.The alax call is working i have test it.

the php file is

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['NDB_No'])) {

     $NDBNo = $_POST['NDB_No'];
    
    global $recipesdb;
    
    $result = $recipesdb->get_results(
"SELECT * FROM IngredientsTable WHERE NDB_No LIKE'$NDBNo%' ORDER BY NDB_No ASC");
if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        foreach($result as $row) {
       echo $row->NDB_No;
}
}
}
```

And although its the same query as in my plugin it gives me an 500 error.
Any ideas why is this happening???

the ajax call is

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:themeurl+"/inc/insert-recipe-and-post.php",
data: "NDB_No="+NDB_No,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){console.log('Connecting...');},
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});

Comment: can you post your full ajax function?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it.
I had to include load.php in my php file.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
```

Thanks anyway